# Using javascript to remove div class

Tags: javascript, css, class, html

I was wondering if it is possible to remove the contents of a specific `div class` using javascript?

I would like to be able to access this div's content occasionally, so I don't want to remove it entirely but I'm worried that it will still take up page loading time, even if it has 
'display: none' applied to it in the CSS. Is this correct?

Is there any JavaScript that will remove the page contents of a specific "div class" so that it does not slow down page loading time?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense what you want to do because by the time the script is run the `div` will be already loaded.

Comment: Instead of removing the contents of the div load the contents on demand. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: How much data are we talking about removing?  If the content is relatively small, the download cost is negligible.  If there is a *lot* of content, you should probably be breaking it up into multiple pages or giving the user better aggregate options.

Comment: The div class content is embedded youtube videos, each of which fetch info such as thumbnails and text from youtube before they are loaded. I have another class that sits in the same parent div in which fancybox launches the embedded video from my own still images, thus eliminating the fetch from youtube. @cimmanon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript works in the client, specifically, manipulating the DOM generated from the document loaded, that means, that if JS can see the object, it already took some time to be loaded.

If you don't want it to be loaded, the best way is to do is not to send it to the client, for instance, using server languages like perl, php, asp. etc.

Other way, is to have a frame in the page, with an empty src, and request that div after the document is loaded, that way, the effect is that the client doesn't have the load of that content in the firs place but will be available for your process later.

Bye

Comment: I'd rather use AJAX than frames, but I guess it still serves the purpose.

Comment: True, but ajax adds more load on the page plus the processing load in the client. The frame has a delayed load and almost not processing time in the client. And the JS used is also simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Removing elements with JavaScript *won't* affect your page's loading time. This is because the page is downloaded, and then the code removes the element *after* the page was loaded. It might even make it *slower* (slightly), since the browser has to execute such code to remove the element.

If you want to make the page loading time shorter, remove the element from your file, and then upload it again to your server.

You could then create this `<div>` dynamically by requesting it through AJAX (as *Dr.Molle* suggested), either using a library or plain JS.

Comment: There's a reason a single sprite map is suggested over multiple small images:  downloading a large piece of data (within reason) is more efficient.  Loading half the page up front and half of it via AJAX doesn't make the site load any faster.

Comment: @cimmanon: That is technically true. The total amount of time for the *entire* website to load is the same (or maybe more). Therefore, I'd only do this if half the website was enough to keep the user entertained while the rest loaded.

Comment: too bad most people aren't interested in being entertained, they're interested in retrieving information.  Most applications using AJAX are doing it for the information retrieval, which is usually what the user would prefer to have *first*.

Comment: @cimmanon: It depends really, whether the *information* in question is primary or secondary (as the primary could be loaded first, and the secondary could be loaded through AJAX later; secondary being extra content). It also depends on the *purpose* of the website.